# Could someone show me how to use this UniformWrapPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, wrappanel

Here is the link describing it: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32629/A-better-panel-for-data-binding-to-a-WrapPanel-in.

I have two questions.

1) In the article the UniformWrapPanel Class is shown. The article makes it clear that the following mothod "private static void IsAutoUniformChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)" is a part of the class, but what about the one after that? Is the "protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)" a part of the UniformWrapPanel class?

2) The article is not clear on how to actually use the UniformWrapPanel. Could someone tell me how to implement it in a project?

Comment: For MeasureOverride, see [How to: Create a Custom Panel Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element)

Comment: There are download source and example project links at the top of that article. Did you try them and look at the code?  From a quick look, I think all that code goes in the one class inheriting from Wrappanel. To use. Download the source of grab all that code. Put it in one class. Either by dragging in or add a class then paste the code you grabbed over the class... part.  Compile. Add a xmlns reference to the namespace. If that can just be local then paste the markup out the article.